# What is element selector of below html using Zend_Dom_Query

Tags: php, regex, zend-studio

```
<div class="product-info" style="min-height: 190px;">
         <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Ottoman" href="">Ottoman</a></h2>
          <div class="price-box">
               <span id="product-price-51" class="regular-price">
               <span class="price">$299.99</span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="ratings">
               <div class="rating-box">
                  <div style="width:69%" class="rating"></div>
               </div>
              <span class="amount"><a onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href=''; return false;" href="#">4 Review(s)</a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
                  <button onclick="setLocation('')" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
                  <ul class="add-to-links">
                       <li><a class="link-wishlist" href="">Add to Wishlist</a></li>
                       <li><span class="separator">|</span><a class="link-compare" href="/">Add to Compare</a></li>
                  </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
```

I want               
`<button onclick="setLocation('')" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>`
From above html using zend_dom_query

Comment: so where's your code? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
use Zend\Dom\Query;

$dom = new Query($html);
$result = $dom->execute('.btn-cart');
```